# css make <br> element appear at start of new line

Tags: html, css

The 'invisible' `<br>` element always appears at the end of the line you wrote it for.
With styling, you can give it a visual appearance. I want to make it appear at the start of the next line instead, so the visual appearance would indicate the start of that line.

```
abc<br style="border:1px solid"/>abc
```

would give

```
 abc|
 abc
```

but i want

```
abc
|abc
```

Comment: Why do you want this? I'm sure there's a better option for your purpose.

Comment: It´s line break (first line break), so I think it´s normal it´s at the end of the first line, not at the beginning of the second line. What you want to do?

Comment: I want to indicate a selected character, including line breaks

Comment: http://jsbin.com/qobivo/edit?html,css,output

Comment: nice, but I cannot use an additional element to provide the effect, its needs to be styled onto the `<br>` element itself

Comment: that < br / > tag isn't a printable character. And if you ***did*** do what some of the answers suggest, it would be ***extremely*** bad practise!!!

Comment: i dont need to print the <br/> element, just style it

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show 
 tag before or after every paragraph for any purpose. you should use pseudo selectors.. `like :before and :after`

```
<html>
<p>hello1</p>
<p>hello2</p>
<p>hello3</p>
<p>hello4</p>

<css>
p:after{
content: "";
border-right: 1px solid red;
margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

“indicate a selected character, including line breaks”

Line breaks are non-printed characters. Most software (e.g. MS Word) uses a replacement character to display line breaks. You should do the same to highlight any line-breaks.

Or you can wrap the line break into another tag which then is styled accordingly:

HTML

```
abc<mark class="line-break-wrapper"><br></mark>abc
```

CSS

```
.line-break-wrapper {
    background: #990;
    padding: 0 .25em;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the first person to actually include in their answer "it's not printable".

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use

```
 abc<br/><span  style="border-left:1px solid ">abc</span>
```

to achieve this 
But i don't think this is the good method

Answer (score -1):

I think giving border is more better see this  http://jsfiddle.net/46jyt4d7/

```
<p>abc<br/></p><p class="a">abc</p>

.a{
border-left:1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't actually style a `<br />` tag to become visible. But to achieve what you want to achieve all you have to do is put another element that creates the line like this:

```
abc<br /><span></span>abc
```

And with the styling:

```
span {
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

Here is an example fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tmqk0ppe/